# Numpy failing on import (ImportError: DLL load failed: The network path was not found.)

Tags: python, numpy

I had python with numpy installed and working fine on my local device for years, but for some reason, I get the error:

> ImportError: Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed. 
>   Most likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy. If
>   you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf` (removes
>   all files not under version control).  Otherwise, reinstall numpy.

The original error was:

> DLL load failed: The network path was not found.

depending on what network I'm connected to. reinstalling seems to fix it but my bigger concern is why the network status affects it at all? What DLL is it trying to find and where is it trying to get it from?